# Es una buena practica utilizar etiquetas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, buenas-prácticas

Estoy estudiando programacion web, y acabo de encontrar este codigo, se que poner "inicio:" se refiere a una etiqueta, y tambien se a que se refiere el "continue inicio;", pero, es esto una buena practica? Primera vez que lo veo. Quisera saber mas de su uso correcto.

```
inicio:
for( let c = 0; c <= 10; c++ ) {
    if( c % 2 !== 0 ) {
        continue inicio;

    }else {
        console.log(c);

    };

};
```

Comment: lee la documentación

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo leer [ask]. Si tienes algunas duda especifica del funcionamiento de una etiqueta o palabra reservada te recomiendo primero revisar la documentación. Tu pregunta se basa más en opiniones que en una respuesta concreta.

Comment: Es probable que mucha gente lo vea como una mala practica, recuerda demasiado al goto. Yo no lo usaría a no ser que quede muy clara la ventaja de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de parecer una pregunta basada en opiniones, creo que es un tema interesante, porque muchos no conocíamos esta característica y podría llegar a ser útil en ciertos casos.

> ¿Es una buena práctica utilizar etiquetas en JavaScript?

No se trata de buena o mala práctica, sino el uso que puedas darle. No hay que confundirlo con sentencias `goto` de otros lenguajes, porque solo aplica en ciclos y únicamente comienza a tener sentido cuando son anidados y quieres controlar el comportamiento de los antecesores.

Al tratarse del mismo ciclo (o ciclo único), no tiene sentido usar etiquetas:

```js
let i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         // Es lo mismo que solo continue, salta esta iteración
         continue loop2;
      }
      // Dos resultados de i = 1
      console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
   }
}
```

Teniendo ciclos anidados, ya puede tener un poco más de sentido:

```js
let i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         // El comportamiento es igual a break (solo en este caso)
         // Termina este ciclo y vuelve al for(i...)
         continue loop1;
      }
      // Solo un resultado de i = 1
      console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
   }
}
```

Creo que la principal ventaja es poder controlar todos los ciclos desde dentro:

```js
let i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         // Todo termina cuando i = 1 y j = 1
         break loop1;
      }
      console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
   }
}
```

Estos ejemplos están basados en la documentación para [label (en inglés)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) y ya imagino las posibilidades al tener 3 o más ciclos anidados.

Tratando de hacer un ejemplo más viable, al buscar un valor específico en un arreglo bidimensional, necesitas dos ciclos, uno para filas y otro para columnas:

```js
// Saber si hay un valor falso en este arreglo
let filas = [
    [true, true, true, true],
    [true, true, false, true],
    [true, true, true, true],
    [true, true, true, true],
];

/* ***** Sin etiquetas ***** */
// Inicializar un par de variables
let falso = false;
let cuenta = 0;
// Recorrer filas
for(let i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
    // Recorrer columnas
    for(let j = 0; j < filas[i].length; j++) {
        if(!filas[i][j]) {
            // Se encontró valor falso
            falso = true;
            // Terminar este ciclo
            break;
        }
        // Valores verdaderos encontrados
        cuenta ++;
    }
    // No hay etiquetas, hay que saber si continuar o no
    if(falso) {
        // Terminar este ciclo
        break;
    }
}
console.log('Sin etiqueta:', cuenta);

/* ***** Con etiquetas ***** */
// Inicializar variables
falso = false;
cuenta = 0;
// Recorrer filas
cicloi:
for(let i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
    // Recorrer columnas, no se necesita etiqueta aquí
    for(let j = 0; j < filas[i].length; j++) {
        if(!filas[i][j]) {
            // Se encontró valor falso
            falso = true;
            // Terminar ambos ciclos
            break cicloi;
        }
        // Valores verdaderos encontrados
        cuenta ++;
    }
    // Hay etiqueta, no es necesario agregar comparación aquí
}
console.log('Con etiqueta:', cuenta);
```

Este es un ejemplo muy sencillo y, seguramente, habrá otras formas de lograrlo, solo es cuestión de experimentar para ver qué puede ser más eficiente y legible, de acuerdo a tus preferencias.

Comment: The labels allow: 
 Be able to create partial scopes to fragment pre-export code as modules. 

'label1: { 
    myCode ... 
}'